# reference array values returned by smarty modifier

Tags: smarty, smarty2

Can someone please tell me how to reference values from an array returned by a smarty modifier

I have a modifier that returns an array

```
$user = array("name"  => $name, "id" => $id, "email" => $email);
return $user;
```

When I try to access the returned values in the template using the code below it just says Array

```
{$member|user_display:"name"}
```

I have tried lots of different ways and if I use `{$member|user_display:"name"|@print_r}` it shows the array structure and values so the information is there just need to get at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything depends what functionality you need.

If you simple want to display value for key your code should look like:

Smarty modifier:

```
function smarty_modifier_user_display($member, $field="name")
{                                                
  // sql searching user  
  $user = array("name"  => 'XXX', "id" => $member.'222', "email" => 'my@example.com');
  return $user[$field];
}
```

Smarty template file:

```
{assign var=member value="3"}
{$member|user_display}
{$member|user_display:"name"}
{$member|user_display:"id"}
{$member|user_display:"email"}
```

But when you have modifier as you showed:

```
function smarty_modifier_user_display($member)
{                                                
  // sql searching user  
  $user = array("name"  => 'XXX', "id" => $member.'222', "email" => 'my@example.com');
  return $user;
}
```

Smarty template file should look like this:

```
{assign var=member value="3"}

{assign var=my_user value = $member|user_display}

{$my_user.name}
{$my_user.id}
{$my_user.email}
```

***You should of course be careful when using modifier - I don't know from what source you get data for your user. But if you do it from database, you shouldn't query database each time because when you launch modifier a couple of times, your database will be unnecessary queried multiple times instead of one.***

Comment: Thanks heaps. I changed it to your first example which was more efficient for what I needed, also helped solve another couple of problems